# Differential Geometry Intuition Question

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition

Apologies if I get the notation wrong. Still learning this stuff.

Suppose I have a 2 dimensional Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ that is covered by a single chart: $\phi: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (or alternatively, let's just think about a single chart).

I can think of this manifold as just the plane that is stretched out in some places and/or shrunk in other places (or directions) depending on the metric $g$. I understand enough calculus and physics to know what to do when someone hands me some metric that depends upon coordinates, say $g = g_{xx}(x,y) dx^2+g_{xy}(x,y) dx dy+ g_{yy}(x,y) dy^2$ So that in that chart, I can do calculations (find the length, etc). But I still struggle with intuition. So here's my question:

Suppose I have some rectangle in the plane with some such metric prescribed. Can I think of this (for the 2D case) as just just like a topographic map? If not, how is the changing metric different from the bumps and valleys of such a map? Any example to help me understand this better will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define what a "topographic map" means. Once you do, I think you will end up with the requirement that your surface is isometric to the graph of a function in 3-space with Riemannian metric induced from the flat metric on $R^3$. This is fine for some intuition but not enough to recover all Riemannian metrics. For instance, hyperbolic plane does not embed isometrically in the flat 3-space.

Edit: Furthermore, there are smooth Riemannian metrics which do not admit isometric (smooth) embeddings in $R^3$ even locally, see, say, [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208127).

Comment: But doesn't a single patch of the hyperbolic plane embed? Not the whole thing of course. Also, I mean a topographic map in the wikipedia sense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographic_map  A map with contour lines to represent height.

Comment: @amcalde: If you want metrics which do not embed even locally, read http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208127. As for "topographic maps": This is not a mathematical concept. When I wrote "define" I meant "define mathematically." Without such definition, you do not have a question.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I still have a question. Namely "Can this not-really-mathematically-rigorous notion of a topographic map help me to understand this concept?"  In fact I want to *avoid* a mathematical definition--that's the point.

Comment: But thanks for the reference! I'll read it. (I think this may be the counter-example that limits the analogy I was thinking of)

Comment: @amcalde: Yes, a topographic map regarded as a surface in $R^3$, can given you a partial intuition.